# Android Studio crashes on start with PluginException

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am not sure whether it worked buefore, but I updated to Android Studio 4.1 today and then tried launching it, only to see the crash below.

The crash happens even when I delete everything from `%appdata%\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins`. It seems that the problem is with the JetBrains Android plugin itself?

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: ComponentConfig{implementationClass='', interfaceClass='com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.impl.DefaultJdkConfigurator', headlessImplementationClass='', loadForDefaultProject=false, options={overrides=true}} does not override anything [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:618)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$2.accept(ApplicationLoader.kt:379)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$2.accept(ApplicationLoader.kt)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1609)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: ComponentConfig{implementationClass='', interfaceClass='com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.impl.DefaultJdkConfigurator', headlessImplementationClass='', loadForDefaultProject=false, options={overrides=true}} does not override anything [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:291)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:194)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:157)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$registerAppComponents$1.apply(ApplicationLoader.kt:93)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$registerAppComponents$1.apply(ApplicationLoader.kt)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    ... 12 more

-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try re-install into a new empty directory. Also try deleting IDE config and caches directories: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#file_location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions, but I ended up simply reinstalling Android Studio. It seems that I somehow had a botched installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go from Android Studio's start menu to Settings-Plugins and just disable and enable again all needed plugins.

Comment: This wouldn’t have worked as Android Studio would crash on launch. No start menu.